# Search specific leaves laravel Baum

Tags: php, laravel

Under my root are 7 main categories (depth 1) with all (nested) children. However I want to return (and later search) only the leaves of certain parents (with type: finder). How can I do this?

It should be something like:

```
$node = Categorie::where('type', 'finder')->getLeaves();
```